# Read content from text file using powershell and store each word in a string array

Tags: powershell

I have a text file like below

John,42,Chicago,Pilot,Male
David,40,Sydney,Artist,Male
Elena,35,London,Designer,Female

I want to read this text file using Powershell and store them in array of variable like below

Name1=John
Age1=42
City1=Chicago
Profession1=Pilot
Gender1=Male

Name2=David
Age2=40
City2=Sydney
Profession2=Artist
Gender2=Male

Similarly for other lines.

I tried with:

```
$DB = Get-Content "File.txt" foreach ($Data in $DB) $First, $Second, $Third, $Fourth = $Data -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
```

however, I am looking for something like this:

Name1=John Age1=42 City1=Chicago Profession1=Pilot Gender1=Male Name2=David Age2=40 City2=Sydney Profession2=Artist Gender2=Male

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? As tip: have a look at [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and the `-Header` parameter

Comment: $DB  = Get-Content "File.txt"
foreach ($Data in $DB) 
$First, $Second, $Third, $Fourth = $Data -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'

however, I am looking for something like this
Name1=John
Age1=42
City1=Chicago
Profession1=Pilot
Gender1=Male

Name2=David
Age2=40
City2=Sydney
Profession2=Artist
Gender2=Male

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are reading as text file is actually a CSV file without headers, I would recommend using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to get the data you need:

```
$DB = Import-Csv -Path "D:\File.txt" -Header 'Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Profession', 'Gender'
```

This way you will have all properties in an array of PsCustomObjects, where you can loop through the various items ('rows') like

Output on screen

```
$DB
```

Or output just the Name and Profession for instance

```
$DB | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} - {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Profession
}
```

Or find the data for a specific name

```
$DB | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Elena' }
```

Or whatever you want to do with the data

Comment: Thanks it works!
but I want to store them to individual variables, coz I want to use them for some other function. Want to store them like this
Name1=John
Age1=42
City1=Chicago
Profession1=Pilot
Gender1=Male

Name2=David
Age2=40
City2=Sydney
Profession2=Artist
Gender2=Male

Comment: I think I got what I needed..

$array  = Get-Content "File3.txt" 
$array = $array -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
"First array value: " + $array[0]
"Second array value: " + $array[1]
"Third array value: " + $array[2]
"fourth array value: " + $array[3]
"fifth array value: " + $array[4]
"sixth array value: " + $array[5]

Thank you Theo!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what I needed..

$array  = Get-Content "File3.txt" 
$array = $array -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
"First array value: " + $array[0]
"Second array value: " + $array[1]
"Third array value: " + $array[2]
"fourth array value: " + $array[3]
"fifth array value: " + $array[4]
"sixth array value: " + $array[5]

Thank you Theo!

Comment: Personally I would strongly advice **against** doing that, especially if the list gets longer and longer. Why not use the 'person' objects in the array you get using my code? You can simply use them by their index like `$DB[0].Name` which would represent your variable `Name1`. `$DB[0].Age` is `Age1` etc. That way you will have all properties for each 'person' together under the same index.